# Puttin a imgae on top of another HTML

Tags: html

```
   <style>
   #wrapper 
  { z-index: 0;}
   #animal
   { z-index: 1;}
    </style>      



   .........
   <div id="wrapper">
   <img src="background.png" width="1300" height="1100" />

   <div id="animal">
   <img src="animal.png" width="200" height="100" />
   </div>
   </div>
```

No, this didn't work, the animal.png is below the back.png, I want it to be on top. 
I like  tag because it allows to scale the image size.

Comment: OK, this work! <div id="wrapper" style="position: relative;">
 <img src="background.png" width="1300" height="1100" />
 
<div id="animal" style="position: absolute; left: 600px; top: 400px; ">
<img src="animal.png" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

Z-index requires that the position property is not static (which is the default value for the property). Try this:

```
#animal
{ position: relative; z-index: 1;}
```

Comment: It doesn't work because animal needs to be absolute and wrapper, container needs to be relative.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant you already had them overlapping, but the animal was not in front.